# Custom back button with the < sign

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

I have a screen in which the user is doing some actions.
When clicking the back button, I want to stop and show an alert to confirm this step.

I have 2 options:

1. Leave the native back button: `< Prev screen` and catch the `-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`. when I'm doing that, It is too late to go back. **I can't stop the back action, can I?**
2. Replace with custom button. That's the easy solution, except I don't have the `<` on the button... Adding this sign as an image looks too cumbersome.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Set the custom button with < image. set the inset of the image like in  default back button.

Comment: that is possible, you just need to inherit a class from `UINagivationController` and you need to override `navigationBar:shouldPopItem:` method... and you have to use your inherited navigation controller handling nagivations instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to create a custom `UIBarButtonItem` with the right type. Using an image is not painful at all.

And no, there is no use trying to prevent the pop action on `UINavigationController`. Also mind the `InteractivePopGestureRecognizer` as of iOS 7.

Comment: How can I know what the image's dimensions should be?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button= [UIButton new];
    //customize your button here
    UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
```

customize your button with your title etc...